# Tailwind CSS responsive breakpoint overrides not working

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css

I can't figure out why the responsive overrides of tailwind are not working in my project.

For example, I'd like the following text in div to be centered below the small screen breakpoint and left-aligned above the sm breakpoint. The following code seems to work when I try it in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/adnanchowdhury/pen/XLgNZp). However, it does not work in my laravel project.

```
<div class="text-grey-4 flex-1 px-6 sm:text-left text-center self-center">  
    <h2 class="h2"><b>Heading Text</b></h2>
    <div>
      Lorum ipsum lorum ispum lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum lorum ispum lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum lorum ispum lorum ipsum
    </div>
 </div>
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work in my Laravel project?

Comment: What is `self-center`? Also, can you show the classes you have for the parent element? Can you also explain what isn't working i.e. is it always in left aligned or in the center...or something completely different?

Comment: your question not about overriding breakpoints. 
your problem is with its usage and implementation.
please change your question title.

Comment: You have an unclosed html tag in the second line, "Heading Text" (</b>). I don't think removing it will make much difference.

Comment: This should be explained way more clearly in the tailwindcss documentation. It never says breakpoints are from low to high. Not high to low

Answer (score 40):

The problem is: Tailwind is a mobile-first framework as [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#mobile-first), which means that the unprefixed `class` props will be used as mobile style, and the style of the prefixed(starting with `sm`, `md`, `lg`) will be used **for that screen breakpoint and above (NOT BELOW)**

So in your case it should be in the opposite way

```
class='text-left sm:text-center'
```

Comment: I get it now! I've been struggling for weeks to understand these breakpoints cascades. Thanks!

Comment: I swear I was about to mad until I read your post. `above` !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Despite the many upvotes, **this answer is wrong**. The question clearly says, “I'd like the following text in div to be centered below the small screen breakpoint and left-aligned above the sm breakpoint”. That means **mobile view = centred** and **larger screen = left-aligned**. Your example does the exactly opposite, making mobile view left-aligned and larger screens centred. The asker has perfectly understood the logic of Tailwind breakpoints and applied it correctly, as also evidenced by the fact that the Codepen in the question works.

Answer (score 23):

Every time you design something with Tailwind, start from mobile.

```html
<div class="text-center sm:text-left">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

So basically on this example. Instead of saying:

> Text should be centered only on smaller devices.

Do this:

> Text should be always centered, and aligned left for bigger devices.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wLeoYV

Comment: The problem is somewhere else, probably in your setup.

Answer (score 6):

If you are overriding the default breakpoints in `tailwind.config.js` file, be sure to follow ascending order of the `screens` values (from smallest to largest viewport):

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'sm': '576px',
      'md': '960px',
      'lg': '1440px',
    },
  }
}
```

This is important because the CSS cascade will be created in the same order. Larger breakpoints will override smaller ones.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, also for people using desktop first layout make sure to arrange them in descending order, then it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of days ago, I encountered a similar issue within my React project.

Specifically, I had integrated **TailwindElements** into the project.

Upon conducting some investigation, I determined that the presence of **TailwindElements** was interfering with the functionality of my TailwindCSS breakpoints.

Consequently, I decided to remove **TailwindElements** from my project, which resolved the issue, and my code began functioning as expected.

***Happy coding!***

**Edited**

*Note* - Yes removing **TailwindElements** works, but what if you still want to use `TailwindElements`?

In such cases, you can override your Tailwind classes that aren't functioning properly.

For instance, if `p-2` isn't working, you can add this class to your `.css` file:

```
.p-2{
    padding:2rem;
}
```

Additionally, if you want to add breakpoints or customize them, please refer to the  [Tailwind Screens documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens).

Comment: similar thing happened to me when I installed TailwindElemets in nuxt.js

Comment: Had similar issue, removing tw-elements worked.

Comment: Removing tw-elements is not a solution; for that, I have edited my answer. Please refer to that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
Check the 'tailwind.config.js' file.
In my case, I forget to add the directory of the file i'm using

Answer (score 0):

i found in my case i had added a meta tag for `<meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui" />` which was changing the breakpoints and this was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

**Output.css was not updated**

I was working on this project built using create-react-app, so idk there might be some issue which does not updates output.css.
So i deleted output.css, package-lock.json and node_modules.
Then I did a:

- npm install
- sudo npx tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./src/output.css

(Note: my input.css is called index.css)
and the breakpoints are now working.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, max-sm:text-center will work.

```
<div class="text-grey-4 flex-1 px-6 max-sm:text-left text-center self-center">  
    <h2 class="h2"><b>Heading Text</b></h2>
    <div>
      Lorum ipsum lorum ispum lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum lorum ispum lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum lorum ispum lorum ipsum
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

sm dont work . design for mobile then modify code using md and lg for larger screen

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).